# Excluding Documents From UITableView

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

Somehow on the simulator, it has gotten the data from a file that doesn't exist, yet persists in the simulator's memory.  Because apps are sandboxed, it must be from an early method that I neglected to delete, but searching through my app's methods, none of them CREATE files, just view them.

My question is this: can data be excluded from a UITableView that is displaying content from the app's

```
\documents
```

folder?  I only want to display files that end in .pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through each file and look for the `suffix` **`.pdf`**. See **[NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) [`hasSuffix`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasSuffix%3a)**